# Matlab Mex compilation error

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I’m using the Random Forest library for Matlab ([link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/randomforest-matlab/downloads)). I’m using it for classification. On Windows it works very well out of the box (precombiled mex files) but I also want to run it on a CentOS cluster.

I have tried to compile it on the cluster by executing `make mex` but I’m getting an error. The output is as follows:

```
rm twonorm_test -rf
rm  tempbuild/*.o *.o -rf
rm *~ -rf
rm *.mexw32 twonorm_test -rf
rm *.mexa64 -rf
rm classRF -rf
rm *.exe -rf
echo 'Compiling classTree.cpp'
Compiling classTree.cpp
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/classTree.cpp -o tempbuild/classTree.o
echo 'Compiling Cokus (random number generator)'
Compiling Cokus (random number generator)
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/cokus.cpp -o tempbuild/cokus.o
echo 'Compiling rfsub.f (fortran subroutines)'
Compiling rfsub.f (fortran subroutines)
gfortran   -O2 -fpic  -c src/rfsub.f -o rfsub.o
echo 'Compiling rfutils.cpp'
Compiling rfutils.cpp
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/rfutils.cpp -o tempbuild/rfutils.o
echo 'Generating Mex'
Generating Mex
mex src/mex_ClassificationRF_train.cpp  src/classRF.cpp tempbuild/classTree.o tempbuild/rfutils.o rfsub.o tempbuild/cokus.o  -o mexClassRF_train -lgfortran -lm -DMATLAB -g
Unknown MEX argument '-o'.
make: *** [mex_classRF] Error 255
```

Does somebody knows how to solve this issue? If you want, you can take RF_MexStandalone-v0.02.zip from the above link and then go to randomforest-matlab/RF_Reg_C/Makefile.

Edit: I have change -o to -output but now the output is the following:

```
rm twonorm_test -rf
rm  tempbuild/*.o *.o -rf
rm *~ -rf
rm *.mexw32 twonorm_test -rf
rm *.mexa64 -rf
rm classRF -rf
rm *.exe -rf
echo 'Compiling classTree.cpp'
Compiling classTree.cpp
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/classTree.cpp -o tempbuild/classTree.o
echo 'Compiling Cokus (random number generator)'
Compiling Cokus (random number generator)
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/cokus.cpp -o tempbuild/cokus.o
echo 'Compiling rfsub.f (fortran subroutines)'
Compiling rfsub.f (fortran subroutines)
gfortran   -O2 -fpic  -c src/rfsub.f -o rfsub.o
echo 'Compiling rfutils.cpp'
Compiling rfutils.cpp
g++ -fpic -O2 -funroll-loops -msse3 -c src/rfutils.cpp -o tempbuild/rfutils.o
echo 'Generating Mex'
Generating Mex
mex src/mex_ClassificationRF_train.cpp  src/classRF.cpp tempbuild/classTree.o tempbuild/rfutils.o rfsub.o tempbuild/cokus.o  -output mexClassRF_train -lgfortran -lm -DMATLAB -g
Building with 'g++'.
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

make: *** [mex_classRF] Error 255
```

I did not find an option `-std=c++11` in the makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory: the option `-o` is not recognized. If you type `mex -help` you see the options `mex` accepts. Try to replace `-o` with `-output`.

**EDIT** regarding the `std=c++11` option, you are probably using an old version of `gcc` compiler. You can either change it to `std=c++0x` which is the equivalent option (but note that some features of the c++11 standard may not be present\implemented), or upgrade to an up-to-date version of `gcc`.

If you need more help, please report the output of `g++ --version`.

Comment: This option is coming from somewhere, e.g the default config used by mex. You can either look for it, or (as I said before) upgrade your compiler/toolchain